# Bad blocks reported by the kernel, none to be found after scanning

Tags: 18.04, nvme, data-corruption, badblocks

Recently a system that I mainly use over SSH stopped working. I rebooted it and it showed error messages (sorry, didn't take a photo) saying the disk needed to be checked. I checked the disk with `fsck` and it said it cleared some orphaned inodes.

I thought that was it but 2 days later again the same thing happened and again I could fixed it with `fsck`.

When I looked at the logs I saw these message for the first occurrence of the problem:

```
Mär 31 11:03:49 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm rm: bg 6695: bad block bitmap checksum
Mär 31 11:03:49 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4) in ext4_free_blocks:4952: Filesystem failed CRC
Mär 31 11:03:49 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm rm: bg 6694: bad block bitmap checksum
Mär 31 11:03:49 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4) in ext4_free_blocks:4952: Filesystem failed CRC
Mär 31 11:03:49 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm rm: bg 6693: bad block bitmap checksum
Mär 31 11:03:49 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4) in ext4_free_blocks:4952: Filesystem failed CRC
Mär 31 11:03:49 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm rm: bg 6698: bad block bitmap checksum
Mär 31 11:03:49 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4) in ext4_free_blocks:4952: Filesystem failed CRC
Mär 31 11:03:49 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm rm: bg 6689: bad block bitmap checksum
Mär 31 11:03:49 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4) in ext4_free_blocks:4952: Filesystem failed CRC
```

And these for the second time:

```
Apr 02 09:16:44 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 4768: bad block bitmap checksum
Apr 02 09:16:44 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 4769: bad block bitmap checksum
Apr 02 09:16:44 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 4770: bad block bitmap checksum
Apr 02 09:16:44 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 4771: bad block bitmap checksum
Apr 02 09:16:44 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 4772: bad block bitmap checksum
Apr 02 09:16:44 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 4773: bad block bitmap checksum
Apr 02 09:16:44 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 4774: bad block bitmap checksum
Apr 02 09:16:44 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 4775: bad block bitmap checksum
Apr 02 09:16:44 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 4776: bad block bitmap checksum
Apr 02 09:16:44 xxxxxxxx kernel: EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 4777: bad block bitmap checksum
```

So I booted the system with a USB flash drive and checked the NVMe drive for bad blocks using `fsck -vcck`. It found no bad blocks. In addition the `smartctl` tool also reports no errors for the drive.

So I'm wondering what could have gone wrong? If there are no bad blocks then what is causing all this? I'm thinking about replacing the drive but without understanding the problem, this solution does not give me confidence that it will not come back again. Any suggestions or ideas?

*The NVMe is a 2 TB Intel 660p with 4 partitions: p1: EFI, p2: swap, p3: /, p4: /home